# Automatic backup using deja dup on 2 location: locally and usbdrive

Tags: permissions, mount, backup, restore, deja-dup

I have setup automatic backup on local folder /home/zoroaster/backup
and everything work fine, backup and restore.

I would like now to setup a second backup on external usbdrive, so that in case local hd broke or fail, I can restore from external usbdrive.

Using GUI of deja dup allow set only 1 storage location.

I would like to know a good way to do this, using a script or maybe sync local backup folder with external.

Also I would like to know if usbdrive should be owned by root or user in this case? Only for the purpose of backup I will use the usbdrive.

At the moment is mounted on /media/zoroaster/Backup and owner is root.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Deja Dup keeps track of files already backed up you can't run it twice with the same result.

If you want to keep two copies of your backup you can wait until the regular backup is finished, and then simply `cp -rp` the directory on local HD to the USB drive. No need for `rsync` or compressing as the data will not change during the copy and are already compressed.

You can automatize this by a cron job starting at a given time after the Deja Dup backup and checking whether Deja Dup has finished its job (e.g. test the output of `pgrep duplicity`).

The backups run by Deja Dup have the permissions `rw-------` and as owner the user who started it. So you can keep it this way for your external drive.

Comment: I edited my answer because there was an important typo (`grep` instead of `pgrep`).

Comment: I see thanks. Any idea how to know when deja dup will do next backup? I have schedule daily backup, but there is not anywhere at which time backup will be executed.

Comment: As I don't use a scheduled backup, I didn't notice that you can't fix a start time. You could do it however by setting 'Automatic backup' to 'off' and start backup by a daily cron job, too.  The command therefore would be `deja-dup --backup`.

Comment: I understand what you mean. Thanks for tip. I will think about it.